# How to make a Contact Group from a Contact Folder in Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I imported a list of about 120 email addresses into a contact folder in Outlook 2010.  I would like to create a contact group from all of the addresses in this new folder.

One way to do this is to enable the folder as an address book and individually click on all the addresses in the list.   Is there a way to add all of the messages in a folder to a contact group simultaneously?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free [Save Email Addresses from Contacts to Contact Group](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookContactsEmailSaveGroup) utility that does exactly what you want. Just select Outlook contact folder(s) with your imported contacts, specify the target (new empty) group of contacts and run the utility.

DISCLAIMER: I recommend this tool because I'm one of the developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.